# Entrust doesn't see permission

Tags: php, laravel, rbac, entrust

I have four permissions in my `permissions` table in DB:

[image]

In my blade template I check for those permissions via directives like so:

```
    @permission('programs')
       dd('code where permission HAS NOT a dot in the name')
    @endpermission

    @permission('programs.store')
       dd('code where permission HAS a dot in the name')
    @endpermission

    @permission('programs.update')
       dd('code where permission HAS a dot in the name')
    @endpermission
```

An authorized user has a role with all the above permissions attached to it, however, code with permission `programs` does not work, while others do.

Why? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Oh....Entrust cached my previous settings for the user, so all you need is update cache each time you change user permission :

```
Cache::tags(config('entrust.permission_role_table'))->flush();
```